# Hard to understand the meaning of "si fece"

Tags: meaning, verbs

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the clause `si fece` which might be an idiom. Seems like reflexive form of `farsi`, but hard to understand the meaning within the sentences such as :

> Ordinò una limonata, andò alla toilette, si sciacquò mani e viso, si fece 
>       portare un sigaro ....

or

> Lindsay era nervosa e si fece una doccia per rilassarsi

or

> Smisero di usare il cimitero e la terra si fece arida.

or

> E si fece saltare le cervella a sessant'anni.

Does that mean `dirigersi` **o** `diventarsi a una cosa` ..?

Comment: It's not *_facersi_, but _farsi_, which in turn is the reflexive form of _fare_.

Comment: exactly @DaG you're right, thanks.

Comment: "Si fece" is the 3rd singular form of "passato remoto" of "farsi". It has different meanings depending on the sentence. "Farsi arida", as you say, is the same as "diventare arida". "Farsi una doccia" means "to have a shower". The other ones have the structure "farsi" + infinitive which more or less mean "to have someone do something for oneself".

Comment: @Charo Sounds like a good answer.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I've converted my comment to answer because I think it's better that an unanswered question. But I believe it should be more elaborated to be a good answer.

Comment: _Si fece_ isn't an idiom; it's just the two words _si_, which means more or less “to him/herself”, and _fece_, which means even more or less “did”.

_Fece_ is a form of the _passato remoto_ of the verb _fare_, which has a very wide spectrum of meanings and uses: in some sense, it combines many of the meanings of the English verbs “to do” and “to make”, with some of “to get”, “to have” and other ones.

Comment: You may have an idea of the number of different uses of this verb from the sheer size of a dictionary's [article on _fare_](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2). Charo's answer explains which of those uses appear in your sentences.

Comment: Grazie mille a tutti ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Si fece" is the third singular form of "passato remoto" of "farsi", which implies that all your sentences express an action that happened in the past. It has different meanings depending on the sentence:

- "Farsi arida", as you say, is the same as "diventare arida", with the meaning of "to become".
- "Farsi una doccia" means "to have a shower".
- The other ones have the structure "farsi" + infinitive which more or less mean "to have someone do something for oneself".

Comment: Grazie mille Charo.